# INTERSECT tool in arcobjects

Tags: arcobjects

I am using geoprocessing tool Intersect in Arcobjects. How to pass two input feature classes in to in_features option in INTERSECT tool could you please tell me how to pass.

```c#
Geoprocessor gp = new Geoprocessor();
ESRI.ArcGIS.AnalysisTools.Intersect Inter = new ESRI.ArcGIS.AnalysisTools.Intersect(); 
Inter.in_features = ????????????????????????????????         
Inter.out_feature_class = "D:\\Temp\\Inter.shp";
gp.OverwriteOutput = true;
gp.Execute(Inter, null);
```

Comment: Did you solve your problem yet? I´m currently working with the Union tool of arcobjects and do not know how to pass the feature classes eather.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/131873)

Answer (score 1):

Add the feature classes to a IGPValueTable object and pass that to the in_features property.

Here is an example showing how to do it for the Union gp but it should give you the gist:
[Building a custom geoprocessing function tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/00010000049w000000.htm)

Scroll down to Parameter DataTypes > Lists.